# Amazon EC2 Server Display Error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, smarty

I have configured `Amazon EC2` Server and install `PHP and MySQL`. I have uploaded my website on it. it is in `smarty`.

Problem is when I update any `.tpl` file, then the server return `white page` as output in Firefox and Chrome return `500 Internal Server Error`. I have surfed everywhere on internet but got nothing.

When I update any `.php` file then the code work nicely. problem is only with `.tpl` file.

Comment: Let me know if my answer helps you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm willing to bet that your templates_c directory is not writable by Apache (identified as apache or httpd, and you can check in your httpd.conf file), or it hasn't been configured correctly during Smarty initialization.

You can try temporarily setting your templates_c directory to 777 permissions to test this hypothesis.

If this ends up being the case, then you'll want to assign group ownership of templates_c to apache, and set the folder permissions to 775. ([They explain this in their documentation.](http://www.smarty.net/quick_install))

Comment: Excellent! Glad to hear you have it running.

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP status of 500, with no page content (Chrome is just being nice and rendering a default error message for you) means that PHP encountered a Fatal Error.

You will need to find out where PHP is configured to log to (usually a file called `php_errors.log`) and see what the error was.

Alternatively, you could *temporarily* allow PHP to output errors to screen, using the [error_reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) setting.

Comment: /var/log/httpd/error_log   Thinking about it too you may need to restart the httpd after updating the template if smarty is using a template cache it may need to be restarted to rebuild the template cache.

Comment: @Dave unless Smarty is somehow caching in memory, restarting the webserver process will make no difference; if you want to clear an on-disk cache, just delete the files in it

Comment: @SumitBijvani Then set one up - read the fine manual here to find out how: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php